# How to remove all special characters in Linux text

Tags: linux, sed, non-printable

[image: vim pic]
How to remove the special characters shown as blue color in the picture [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gv4Dd.png) like: ^M, ^A, ^@, ^[. In my understanding, ^M is a windows newline character, I can use `sed -i '/^M//g'` to remove it, but it doesn't work to remove others. The command `dos2unix` doesn't work, neither. Are there exist any ways that I can use to remove them both?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Remove everything except the printable characters (character class `[:print:]`), with `sed`:

```
sed $'s/[^[:print:]\t]//g' file.txt
```

`[:print:]` includes:

- `[:alnum:]` (alpha-numerics)
- `[:punct:]` (punctuations)
- space

The ANSI C quoting (`$''`) is used for interpreting `\t` as literal tab inside `$''` (in `bash` and alike).

Comment: I think `tr` would do this faster: `tr -d '[[^:print:]\t]' < file.txt`

Comment: @chthonicdaemon: Good idea, but you probable meant `tr -dC '[:print:]\t\n'` (can't use `^` with `tr`, and the outer `[]`would be taken as characters to match; also need to preserve `\n`).

Comment: @heemayl: Thanks for updating; it's great to show a solution that works with BSD Sed too (and I would keep that solution (too)), but it's worth noting, given that the question is tagged `linux`, that a regular single-quoted string will do with _GNU_ Sed, which does understand `\t` natively. Alternatively, replacing `\t` with `[:blank:]` would bypass the issue.

Answer (score 10):

To ensure that the command works with limited scope in Sed, force use of the ["C" (POSIX) character classifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01_01) to avoid unpredictable behavior with non-ASCII characters:

```
LC_ALL=C sed 's/[^[:blank:][:print:]]//g' file.txt
```

Comment: Good point, but just to state it explicitly: Your solution also removes non-ASCII _letters_, such as `é`.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for the correction and you got the point, that is the problem of which character is in or out of the scope. Only the OP could know because he know the context

Answer (score 4):

Try running below command on linux command prompt

**Option - 1: (If dos2unix command is installed on Linux machine)**

```
dos2unix sample_file.txt
```

**Option - 2:**

```
cat sample_file.txt | tr -d '\015' > new_sample_file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for this but would you mind just helping me understand what "tr -d '\015' does?

Comment: It deletes the character with octal code 015 which is carriage return in ASCII but could be something else in a different encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Try this inside vi or vim:

[[in ESC mode] type: :%s/^M//g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4udE.png)

or:

```
sed -e "s/^M//" filename > newfilename
```

**Important**: To enter ^M, type CTRL-V, then CTRL-M